# different columns on select query results different costs

Tags: performance, oracle, indexing

There is an index at table `invt_item_d` on `(item_id & branch_id & co_id)` columns.
The plan results for the first query are `TABLE ACCESS FULL` and cost is `528`,
results for the second query are `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` (my index) and cost is `27`.

The only difference is, as you can see, the selected column is used in index on the second query.

Is there something wrong with this? And please, can you tell me what should I do to fix this at db administration level?

```
select d.qty
  from invt_item_d d 
 where d.item_id = 999 
   and d.branch_id = 888 
   and d.co_id = 777

select d.item_id
  from invt_item_d d 
 where d.item_id = 999 
   and d.branch_id = 888 
   and d.co_id = 777
```

EDIT:
i made a new query and this query's cost is 529, with TABLE ACCESS FULL.

`select qty from invt_item_d`

so it doesn't matter if i use an index or not. Some says this is normal, is this a normal behaviour really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the table must be accessed, since the "qty" column is only stored in the table.

In the second case, all the columns used in the query can be read from the index, skipping the table read altogether.

You can add another index on columns (item_id, branch_id, co_id, qty) and it will most probably be used in the first query.

From the Oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm

> A fast full index scan is a full index scan in which the database
>   accesses the data in the index itself without accessing the table, and
>   the database reads the index blocks in no particular order.
>
> Fast full index scans are an alternative to a full table scan when
>   both of the following conditions are met:
>
> - The index must contain all columns needed for the query.
> - A row containing all nulls must not appear in the query result set. For this result to be guaranteed, at least one column in the
>     index must have either:
>
>   - A NOT NULL constraint
>   - A predicate applied to it that prevents nulls from being considered in the query result set

Comment: @leitmotif the first answer was already the correct answer (IMHO), why do you ignore it?

Comment: because all the columns at where clause exists on index. index is not for what you are selecting, for what you are filtering. so, this is not a right answer

Comment: @leitmotif - you are wrong. Columns in index can be used also for what you are selecting. There is no need to access the table, if all the data is already present in the index.

Comment: yes you are right, but that's not index's primary job. so, do you propose 'create index for every selected columns'?

Comment: as i mentioned in another comment here, i created another table with different name, with same structure. the query works fine on that table. i still don't understand. i executed gather stats etc also

Comment: Well primary or secondary, it doesn't matter. Oracle examines different access paths and chooses the one with the lower cost. Based on your data structures (table, indexes) and data itself (statistics) it came up with the Fast full index scan.

Comment: I certainly don't propose to create an index for every selected column. It depends on the data (how much rows), on the application (how many inserts, how many reads), on the data distribution (how many branches, items, co_id's), on the sql itself. You can only optimize, if you have an in-depth knowledge of the problem.

Comment: maybe i couldn't explain. the query doesn't use index, and makes a full table scan. as i know, it should use the index with the columns on where condition, because they exactly fit the index. and after reaching appropraite rows, db should get rowid's and get that few rows by those rowid's.

Comment: You are right, Oracle could also do that. But it figured out that the cost of doing that is greater than the cost of reading the full table. The full table scan or fast full index scan can use faster disk read operations, while the index access and table access by rowid can not. If you really want Oracle to use your plan, you could use a hint to force that plan and observe the cost of that plan.

Comment: anyway, i guess there is something wrong with the stats. as i told, i created another table with another name with same index and structure, and index was used and cost reduced. thanks

Comment: Another table with same structure and data can have different stats, sure. The original table is probably from production, where you inserted some rows, then deleted some, then inserted again, deleted again, and so on. The table grows big, you have some unused space in the data blocks, in the index blocks, etc. The physical structure is totaly different than the structure of your newly created table, where the data is still compacted, maybe even sorted. Have a look at the table statistics - BLOCKS and index statistics - CLUSTERING FACTOR. Do they differ a lot?

Comment: sorry, i dont know much about db administration. i am a developer and i have some knowledge about how indexes work, not more.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the main purpose of using index -- make search faster.
Querying columns with indexes are faster compared to querying columns without indexes.

Its basic oracle knowledge.

Comment: i think indexes matter when you use columns with the index in where clause.

Comment: anyway i guess i misunderstood what TABLE ACCESS FULL is. would be bad if it was table full scan

Comment: TABLE ACCESS FULL would mean that the whole table(each and every row) will be scanned, compared and the matching rows will be returned. If the table is pretty huge(Several millions of rows), the perfonce of the query will suffer, i.e. will take more time to execute. With fewer rows, (say few thousands of rows), however, it doesnt really matter.

I think you are right though, that indexes matter when the columns with the index are in the where clause. But for some reason, your first query is not hitting the index, but your second query is.

Comment: ok, i get it. i doesn't hit the index because there are 34000 rows, not millions. but this query is hit 4000 times in a loop and it slows down the process. i think there is nothing i can do, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am adding another answer because it seems to be more convinient.

First:
" i doesn't hit the index because there are 34000 rows, not millions". This is COMPLETELY WRONG and a dangerous understanding.

What I meant was, if there are a few thousand rows, and the index is not hit(oracle engine does a full table scan(TABLE ACCESS FULL) then), its not a big deal. Oracle is fast enough to read few thousand rows in a matter of a second(even without indexes) , and hence you wont feel the difference.The query is still slower(than the occasion when there is an index) , but its is so minimally slower that you wont feel the difference. 
But, if there are millions of rows, the execution of the query will be much, much slower without index ( as this time it will scan millions of rows in a full table scan)and your performance will be hit.

Second: Why on earth do you have to loop over a table with 34000 rows, that too 4000 times???
Thats a terrible approach. Avoid loops as much as possible.There has to be a better approach!

Third:
You can force the oracle optimiser to hit the index by using the index hint.You will need to know the name of the index for that.

```
select /*+ index(invt_item_d <index_name>) */
       d.qty
  from invt_item_d d 
 where d.item_id = 999 
   and d.branch_id = 888 
   and d.co_id = 777
```

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838094/force-index-use-in-oracle) to a stack overflow question on index hint

Comment: i tried to force query to use index but it returned with worse results. then i created another table with same structure and indexes, and inserted all 34000 rows to the new table. then when i ran the query with the new table, results are better (cost=250). after that i thought the problem is about the stats, executed gather stats for invt_item_d table and for index, but still i don't get better results, even it got a bit worse (cost was 528, now it is 550)