# oracle create index on column length with condition

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I had a column name `imsi` and the length of column should be `15` characters, can we create an index based on length of column with condition

i already created an index on `length(imsi)` , but i want all the records where `length(imsi)<>15`, but the query is taking long time, where as for `length(imsi)<15` gives output in milliseconds.
but i want the output where `length(imsi) <> 15`

```
select * from msisdn_data where length(imsi)<> 15
```

or

```
select * from customer_data where length(imsi)>15 or length(imsi)<15
```

both the queries takes long time

Comment: Could you show me the current execution plans of two queries?

Comment: `| Id  | Operation         | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |               |   361K|   613M|   625K  (1)| 00:00:25 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| CUSTOMER_DATA |   361K|   613M|   625K  (1)|`

Comment: for both the queries full table scan is happend

Comment: As you mentioned, `length(imsi)<15` gives output in milliseconds. What about `length(imsi) > 15` ?

Comment: both as individual it gives output in milliseconds where as with or clause full table scan is happening

Comment: Have you tried two solutions below:


1) Use index hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838094/force-index-use-in-oracle

2) UNION to combine two queries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231560/discussion-between-anh-duc-ng-and-sriman-narayana).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_REWRITE_INTEGRITY = TRUSTED; 
ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_REWRITE_ENABLED = TRUE;
```

- The function invoked involve in the index expression must be deterministic. It means that for the same input, the function always
  returns the same result.
- The query optimizer can use a function-based index for cost-based optimization, not for rule-based optimization. Therefore, it does not use a function-based index until you analyze the index itself by invoking either DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS or DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS.

Or you can use Hint.

```
SELECT /*+ index(msisdn_data imsi_idx) */ * 
FROM msisdn_data WHERE LENGTH(imsi) <> 15;
```

For more information on why the function-based index is not used in your query, refer the link

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_statistics_function_based_index.htm